# FSP Zen power supply flaw or what?

Tags: boot, power-supply, freeze, nvme

I have an old FSP ZEN 300W power supply (reviewed [here](https://silentpcreview.com/fortron-source-zen-fanless-300w-atx12v-power-supply/)). I have a new desktop config that I wanted to utilize this beast for but unfortunatelly failed.

The config consist of a Gigabyte Aorus Pro 550i mother board Kingston RAM and a Ryzen 5650 APU. I also have an M2 NVMe flash.

When I turn on the system, the disks and the cpu vent spin up but no output is shown (I don't have a speaker to check if the MB gives any other signs). Once, disconnecting the SATA disk I could get the OS started, but after a couple of minutes it froze.

Using a different Power supply (also 300W), the system works normally. I tried removing the NVMe flash and with that removed, BIOS booted properly. I had however no way of knowing if this made the system stable or not, since there was no OS to test with.

I had the FSP ZEN examined by an eletrician and he claimed that the PS works fine, very stable even when under load. He tried pushing the limits on the relevant (+3.3V, +5V, +12V) voltages but found no problems at all.

Could you give me any hints on how to proceed resolving this issue? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) What was the make and model of the "different Power supply"? 2) Also, neither [AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/processors/ryzen) nor Gigabyte's [CPU compatibility list](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX-rev-10/support#support-cpu) for that motherboard list a "Ryzen 5650" - are you sure about the part number? 3) A 15-year-old PSU is likely to have decaying capacitors: did the electrician test it with an ATX PSU tester, loading more than one voltage rail at the same time?

Comment: The other Power supply that works is a cheap one labeled Codegen 300W. Curiously the model number is 250X. The Gigabyte [compatibility matrix](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX-rev-10/support#support-cpu) shows my CPU (Ryzen 5 Pro 5650G) as supported. 
In fact, the electrician tested for the capacitors. He found one that was below specs and replaced that, but even before replacing it he was able to measure outputs according to the test. 
He does not have an ATX PSU tester, instead he used his working configuration with known power loads.

Comment: He was able to get stable outputs even under load on all voltage levels. I do not know the exact method he used for adding loads.

Comment: Oh, sorry, now I see it in the compatibility matrix. You could try measuring the voltages at the M/B end of the power connectors, but there's always the possibility of damaging something while poking around with multimeter probes. The manual recommends at least a 500 W PSU. Maybe the FSP PSU has some unfortunate interaction with the power draw of the M/B at startup.

Comment: When I disconnect the NVMe modul it works fine. I tried to find the specs for the NVMe power draw characteristics but found none. I have an idea and I may be wrong about it: the PCIe power is supplied through a separate MB connector, right? The specs for the ZEN FSP PSU suggests that there is a minimum of 1A (and a maximum or either 8 or 14 amps) on the +12V connector. The codegen does not have a minimum power load requirement. Could it be, that since there is no other load on the PCI slot, less than 1A is being drawn and the PSU simply shuts down the related circuit?